# Problems building OpenSSL 1.1.0c for Android against NDK 15.2

Tags: macos, build, openssl, sqlcipher

When running build-openssl-libraries.sh, I come across following problems:

Warning when it runs ./Configure dist at line 48:

```
The library could not be configured for supporting multi-threaded
applications as the compiler options required on this system are not known.
See file INSTALL for details if you need multi-threading.

The options 'shared', 'pic' and 'dynamic-engine' aren't supported on this
platform, so we will pretend you gave the option 'no-pic', which also disables
'shared' and 'dynamic-engine'.  If you know how to implement shared libraries
or position independent code, please let us know (but please first make sure
you have tried with a current version of OpenSSL).
```

Error when it runs build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh @line 75:

```
HOST_OS=darwin
HOST_EXE=
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_TAG=darwin-x86_64
HOST_NUM_CPUS=4
BUILD_NUM_CPUS=8
ERROR: Failed to create toolchain.
```

Because of this error subsequent compile of .c files fail saying stdlib.h not found.

Please help me to find out how I can build it successfully... On Android I would need multi-threaded support.

- What are the implications of ignoring the two ./Configure warnings
- How to get Make toolchain succeed?

I am running on macOS Sierra 10.12.6. This is part of building SQLCipher.

Comment: What process are you using to build the OpenSSL library for Android? Please provide a link to the docs.

Comment: @jww git clone https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher.git

Comment: @jww Please see this link: https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/open-source/. Basically clone as above and follow instructions in README.org. But it is not smooth.  However if you just want SQLCipher for Android without changes you can just include compile 'net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.7@aar' according to https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-for-android/

Comment: @jww if you are asking about building just OpenSSL, there is a shell script build-openssl-libraries.sh after you clone the above git..

Answer (score 1):

I have updated the build script for building OpenSSL using the Android NDK r15c for SQLCipher for Android [here](https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher/blob/gradle/android-database-sqlcipher/build-openssl-libraries.sh) currently. Would you give that a try?

Comment: I managed to build it.. the link problem was because NDK15 has deprecated stuff.. and there was a flag to override.. Still I will try the updated script and get back.. Thanks..

Comment: any idea if SQLCipher will upgrade to latest version of SQLite? Currently it is based on 3.15.2 while SQLite has released 3.21+..

Comment: I cloned freshly and ran make init and ran into following issues:
(1) android update project -p /Users/arun/test/android-database-sqlcipher
Error: The project either has no target set or the target is invalid.
Please provide a --target to the 'android update' command.
(2) Warnings because of ./Configure dist are still coming..
(3) Still showing ERROR: Failed to create toolchain.
After that it fails during compile of aes.c showing /bin/sh: arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: command not found

Comment: Try the `gradle` branch instead.

Comment: I saw you are upgrading to 3.20.1... I cloned android-database-sqlcipher freshly and ran "make build". But getting issue :android-database-sqlcipher:buildNative FAILED
When I ran in gradle debug mode, it gives many errors on compiling sqlite3.c starting with:

[armeabi] Compile thumb  : sqlcipher <= sqlite3.c
/Users/arun/SQLCipher3_20/android-database-sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher/src/main/cpp/../external/sqlcipher/sqlite3.c:34726:42: error: 
      use of undeclared identifier 'close'
  { "close",        (sqlite3_syscall_ptr)close,      0  },

Comment: Appreciate your upgrading to 3.20.1.. thanks.. but running into issues building it.. pls see above..

Comment: Problem solved now.. after adding -DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC in Android.mk and hardcoding path for ndk-build in native.gradle..

Answer (score 0):

The two warnings disappeared when I changed the line "./Configure dist" to "./Configure android".

The make toolchain problem was because the parameters were passing android-9 while the NDK15 supports only from android-14. As someone has suggested, this was discovered by enabling --verbose for make-toolchain command.

Now the script compiles all .c files but facing problems during link (apps/openssl.o:openssl.c:function main: error: undefined reference to 'stpcpy'). Looks like again some problem with Configure or NDK config..

Writing as answer for anyone who may face the same issue..